# Windows 8 installation fails on Macbook Pro

Tags: windows-8

I'm using a Macbook Pro (early 2011) and I want to change my Windows OS from Windows 7 to Windows 8.

I burnt the Windows 8 installer to a Dual-layer DVD then used Boot Camp Assistant to restore and recreate a partition for my new Boot Camp, and started the installation. I'm already on the setup of Windows 8 when I see the error message:

```
"No media device you windows needs is missing" (something like that).
```

What would be the problem?

Comment: Sorry but you're going to need to give the exact error. That one makes no sense.

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna take a snapshot of the problem.

Comment: It sounds like image used to burn the DVD was corrupt.  I suggest you make sure that Boot Camp is the current version ( or at least the version your using supports Windows 8 ) and you attempt to download and burn the image again.

Comment: @Simkill
Here is the snapshot of my problem,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kja2t3gqxu33qee/CAM00071.jpg

Comment: @Ramhound
My Boot Camp current version is 3.0.4 which is from application installer of MacOS SL. How can I update my Boot Camp? It doesn't show up on Software Update.

The image I used is working. I tried using it on a USB flash drive ( to install Windows 8 on notebook without DVD ROM ).

Comment: @EriezeLagera - Sounds like the underline issue is with Boot Camp if thats the case.  Were you able to sucessfully use the USB flash drive to install Windows 8 and did you try that instead of the DVD?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see, that's flagging up because windows doesn't have necessary drivers to detect your hard drives. You'll need compatible drivers for windows to be able to see your hard drives. You'll probably need to get windows 8 compatible chipset drivers on to a cd, hit browse and navigate to the sata drivers for the system to load.

Just got this from wiki:

> with the release of Boot Camp 4.0 for Mac OS X Lion, only
>   installations of Windows 7 are officially supported.

So, Windows 8 might not ever work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got my problem solved!

The first installer I used, which fails, was burned in MacOS X using Disk Utility as burner. So I buy another blank DVD and burned in Windows 8 ( my other laptop ) using Ashampoo as burner. Luckily after restoring and creating new partition for the Boot Camp, the setup of Windows 8 flows smoothly with no errors now. I think MacOS native burner is having some problems in burning large files.

Thank you for immediate response my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing Windows 8 on a Macbook Pro, however I just got a different installation disc which was also burnt using Mac disk utility and it worked fine.

The first iso was downloaded from Microsoft, not sure why it didn't work.